# pandas np.where add value in another column based on the value in another column from a csv

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a csv of terms and their description.
Once read in the TERM can be found by `fish_montype['TERM']`
The description `fish_montype['SCOPE_NOTE']`

In the dataframe `gdfx` I already have terms in the column `gdfx['montype']` I want to add the description (scope note) to the column `gdfx['mondesc']` based on the value in the montype column.

I'm assuming I need to use `np.where` and I can use this to do a find/replace (as below).

```
    fish_montype = gpd.read_file("domains/FISH/monument_type/thesaurus_terms.csv")
    gdfx['mondesc'] = np.where(gdf['montype'] == '-', gdf['Context Interpretation'], gdf['montype'])
```

How do I alter this to achieve my goal?

EDIT data

fish_montype (csv)

```
TERM,SCOPE_NOTE
DITCH,"a description about a Ditch",
DITCHED ENCLOSURE,"another description",
Diver Attraction,"a good description",
DIVER BATTERY,"a further description",
```

In the gdfx

```
        montype     mondesc
0         DITCH       DITCH
1         DITCH         NaN
2         DITCH         NaN
3         DITCH         NaN
4         DITCH       DITCH
```

the mondesc needs the SCOPE_NOTE associated with the TERM DITCH, overwriting the current mondesc is acceptable.

Expected result:

```
        montype     mondesc
0         DITCH       a description about a Ditch
1         DITCH       a description about a Ditch
2         DITCH       a description about a Ditch
3         DITCH       a description about a Ditch
4         DITCH       a description about a Ditch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) values by second `DataFrame` and assign to column `mondesc`:

```
print (fish_montype)
    TERM SCOPE_NOTE
0  DITCH        AAA

gdfx['mondesc'] = gdfx['montype'].map(fish_montype.set_index('TERM')['SCOPE_NOTE'])
print (gdfx)
  montype mondesc
0   DITCH     AAA
1   DITCH     AAA
2   DITCH     AAA
3   DITCH     AAA
4   DITCH     AAA
```

Comment: thanks, nearly, I added some sample code. I always find np.where to be the solution, but it works in so many ways it's tricky to understand. The current code is adding the TERMto the mondesc rather than the actual description.

Comment: @SpatialDigger - How looks `print (fish_montype[['TERM','SCOPE_NOTE']])` ? Is possible add to answer instead all columns?

Comment: @SpatialDigger - Do you think replace `NaN`? Or `-` ?

Comment: ignore my original coding, I've simplified the data/code, thanks